# Как убрать панель задач?

Tags: windows

У меня Windows 10 home и я не могу убрать панель задач для MyDockFinder. Мне нужно не скрыть, а удалить как будто ее в коде и в задумке никогда не было.

Comment: Через реестр надо поменять shell. Но там и куча другого отвалится